# Template Python list with default element values

Tags: python, list, templates, element, default

I am generating 6-item lists by reading tab-delimited values in a file (one list per line). Some of the tab-delimited values are empty (zero length) or non-existent (e.g., only 4 values on a line). For such cases, I can have an if-else loop to make the new list's elements take certain default values that I define in a 'template' list, but what is the simplest way?

```
template_list = [0, 0, 'X', 0, 'Y', 'Z']
...
new_data = line.strip().split('\t')
...
new_list = new_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the rows already split into fields (e.g. originating from csv.reader) could pare this down to a one-liner list comprehension.

```
template_tuple = (0, 0, 'X', 0, 'Y', 'Z')
template_tuple_len = len(template_tuple)

def extract_normalized_fields_from_row(row):
    split_row = row.strip().split('\t')
    return [v if len(v) else template_tuple[i] for (i, v) in enumerate(
            split_row + [''] * (template_tuple_len - len(split_row)))]

for row in (
    '\t'.join(('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')),
    '\t'.join(('1', '', '3', '4', '5', '6')),
    '\t'.join(('1', '2', '3', '4'))
    ):
    print extract_normalized_fields_from_row(row)
```

A bit uneasy on the eyes, the following portion of the code simply serves to right-pad split_row with whatever number of empty string elements is necessary for its length to equal that of template_tuple. This assumes that all row fields, including those extracted from short rows, are left-aligned with respect to template_tuple.

```
split_row + [''] * (template_tuple_len - len(split_row))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
['1', 0, '3', '4', '5', '6']
['1', '2', '3', '4', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Alternative, a little too dense for my palate, one-liner that produces the same output:

```
template_tuple = (0, 0, 'X', 0, 'Y', 'Z')
template_tuple_len = len(template_tuple)

for row in (
    '\t'.join(('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')),
    '\t'.join(('1', '', '3', '4', '5', '6')),
    '\t'.join(('1', '2', '3', '4'))
    ):
    print [v if len(v) else template_tuple[i] for split_row in
           (row.strip().split('\t'),) for (i, v) in enumerate(
            split_row + [''] * (template_tuple_len - len(split_row)))]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well. I do wonder if there is a simpler operation that can take care of this, some type of list comprehension.

Comment: The first solution does use a list comprehension to accomplish everything aside from splitting the row into fields, which will be done for you if using csv.reader. Perhaps not simpler, but certainly more concise, I've added a second solution that rolls the splitting task into the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```
template_list = [0, 0, 'X', 0, 'Y', 'Z']

def read_from(line):
    new_data = line.split('\t',5)
    full_data = []
    i = 0
    for a in new_data:
        if len(a) < 1:
            a = template_list[i]
            i = i + 1
        full_data.append(a)
    return full_data

# I assumed that you have 5 tab delimeters for your 6 items but
# some of the locations have no data between delimiters
# and the intent is that they then take a default value
print read_from('11\t\tV\t4\t\tT')
print read_from('\t42\tR\t3\tV\tT')
print read_from('\t\t\t\t\t')
```

Sample Output:

['11', 0, 'V', '4', 0, 'T']

[0, '42', 'R', '3', 'V', 'T']

[0, 0, 'X', 0, 'Y', 'Z']

Comment: Thanks. This works well though I was really wondering if there was a simpler way.